# What is a good alternative to Toad for Mac OSX?

Tags: sql, macos, oracle, xmltype

I am looking for an alternative to Oracle's Toad for Mac OS X. I currently use this for work on a Windows machine, but I would like to use it natively in OSX.

I am looking for something that specifically handles XMLTYPEs well.

Comment: What about oracle's SQLDeveloper - java, and free.

Comment: You might want to look at [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio.html) which supports OSX (among other platforms) and Oracle (along with a large number of other databases).  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No love for SQL Developer by Oracle?(Oops sorry didn't see it was mentioned earlier so I'll just second it.) We used to use TOAD exclusively but due to budgetary issues we reluctantly moved to SQL Developer. It was painful but after an adjustment period it is not bad. Does 95% of the functionality we used in TOAD. They do have a certified MacOS version :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

good luck!

P.S. it's free! it's not bad for a free product really...

Answer (score 4):

Quest has released [Toad Mac Edition v1.0 Beta](http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/628.aspx)

> Toad- Mac Edition is a native Mac application for database
>   development. Designed to help database developers be more productive,
>   the Toad - Mac Edition provides essential database tools for Oracle,
>   MySQL, and PostgreSQL.
>
> Boost your database development productivity on Mac and develop
>   highly-functional database applications fast.

Comment: Toad Mac Edition exists no more. Now is Toad Edge, but only works with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SQL WorkBench, it works based on Java and JDBC Drivers, so you can connect to any database that supports jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

I use squirrel sql. Its written in java so can work on multiple OS. It uses JDBC to connect. I use it because I need to connect to oracle, DB2, and teradata.